# How to make webpack to ignore a link tag in the html template?

Tags: webpack, webpack-5

I have a link tag in my html template < link href="styles/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">. I'm going to modify it dynamically to point at styles/bootstrap.rtl.min.css depending on user preferences. Both css are copied using CopyWebpackPlugin. Is there any way to prevent webpack5 from processing this link tag?

Answer (score 0):

You can load this link tag(s) into webpack's vendor property (array). And then, to split your code into vendor and application, you may want to use `ComonChunkPlugin` from webpack, like this:

```js
module.exports = {
  //...
  entry: {
    vendor: ['jquery', 'other-lib'],
    app: './entry',
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
      name: 'vendor',
      filename: "vendor.bundle.js",
      minChunks: Infinity,
    }),
  ],
};
```

To know more about this you can visit [this link](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/commons-chunk-plugin/)